# Can I customize share button in blogger.com new themes

Tags: html, blogger, socialshare

I'm Thai and my blog content is Thai language. In the blogger new themes, the share button is grouped together in "Share" button. However, when it is translate to Thai language, the word "Share" is translate to "ใช้ร่วมกัน" (use together). It strange to translate like that.

How can I manually change the word "Share" of share button in blogger new themes?

---

I already ask at the blogger helper forum. The expert there answer that the option to change word "Share" is impossible for now and suggest me to ask in this forum about advance coding to customize share buttion.
I study a bit about it in stacker overflow. Some clips teach me to change the contents below  but I can't find this  in html code of bloger new themes.

Please someone help me to customize share button of blogger new themes :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this bug is in the translation, the best way forward would be to report this to Blogger so that it gets fixed for all the users using Thai language in the dashboard.

Meanwhile, you can use the following CSS to change the Share button text -

```
button.sharing-button {
    font-size: 0;
}

button.sharing-button:after {
    content: "Share";
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Replace the `content` property's text with whatever you want to be shown.

Comment: Glad that I could help, do accept the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers